# How to get file names of a folder in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, file-io

I want the file names of a particular folder in c#.

I am using Following code

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

I do not want to use getfiles function because it locked by process.I want only file names, not whole path.

How can I do this?

Here is my full code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("Import\\")))
    {
        if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
            try
            {
                FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Import\\" + FileUpLoad1.FileName));
                Label1.Text = FileUpLoad1.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        else
        {
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label1.Text = "No File Uploaded.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Import\\"));
        if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
            try
            {
                FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Import\\" + FileUpLoad1.FileName));
                Label1.Text = FileUpLoad1.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        else
        {
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label1.Text = "No File Uploaded.";
        }
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Import"));
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();

        foreach (var item in filePaths)
        {
            PdfPage pdfPage = new PdfPage();
            pdfPage.Size = PageSize.Letter;
            pdfDoc.Pages.Add(pdfPage);
            using (var pdfGfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage))
            {
                pdfGfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(item), 0, 0);
            }
        }

        pdfDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("PDF\\")+ "vivek.pdf");
        pdfDoc.Dispose();
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Label1.Text = "pdf sucessfully created.";

}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath("Import\\"),true);
}
```

Button 1 is for import and 
Button 2 is for create pdf from jpg and
Button 3 is for delete jpg files

Comment: you forgot the code which causes *locked by process*

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Show us the code otherwise we may suggest code you already think is not working.

Comment: after that actually i want to delete those files.when i used getfiles function it can't be deleted.

Comment: Show all code. You doing something wrong

Comment: if deleting the files fails the Method GetFiles isn't the cause of the problem

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below code to get the name of the files without the complete path

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyDir\");
List<string> filenames = dirInfo.GetFiles().Select(i => i.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyDir\");
FileInfo [] files = di.GetFiles();

files[0].Name ... // this is just name of the file
files[0].FullName ... // this is the full pathname of the file    
files[0].Delete(); // will delete first of the files in list - just example
```